# Adding an editable row to Antd Table?

Tags: reactjs, antd

With material-table they have a property to add an editable row where an empty, editable row to the table, accepting input. I would like to have the same behavior for Ant's Table component. You can find an example of that behavior here under the editable drop down toggle at the bottom: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable They also have a property for setting the new row to be at the top which I also want..

Has anyone done this or seen this?

I currently have an editable Ant table but I'm not sure how I could merge the logic to add a row to the top of the table and then edit that row.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example provided on Antd site https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row.

About `Add` button, you can easily add a new row with empty state

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any ideas on how the new row could be added to the top of all of the rows to be visible without needing to adjust what columns are visible?